# How to search an executable in $PATH in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a ruby function to search for an executable in (Linux) system path?

I know I can do this:

```
path = `which ls` # found if $?.exitstatus == 0
```

But it there a ruby way? Something like:

```
find_in_path('ls') # => '/bin/ls'
```

Comment: Read the answer - I take it that is no builtin method for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`find_executable`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/find_executable)

```
>> require 'mkmf'
=> true
>> find_executable 'ls'
checking for ls... yes
=> "/bin/ls"
>> find_executable 'no-such-command'
checking for no-such-command... no
=> nil
```

Comment: Wonder why it is undocumented...thanks anyway. Maybe stick to manually searching the ENV['PATH']

Comment: Undocumented, because it's for [internal use only](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.1.2/symbols/MakeMakefile/find_executable0).